# RecycleView adapter data show wrong when scrolling too fast

Tags: android, listview, drawing, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a custom Recycle View adapter that list my items. in each Item I check database and draw some circles with colors.

when I scroll listview very fast every drawed data ( not title and texts) show wrongs!
how I can manage dynamic View creation without showing wrong data?!

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) { 
        itemViewHolder.date.setText(items.get(i).getData()); // set the title

        itemViewHolder.relative_layout_tag_place.addView(generateTagImages(items.get(i).getServerId()));  // had to generate a Relativelaout with 

}
```

and this is `importMenuTags():`

```
   private RelativeLayout generateTagImages(String serverId) {

        List<String> color_list = new ArrayList<>();
    RelativeLayout result = new RelativeLayout(context);
    List<String> list = db.getCardTags(serverId);

        int i = 0;
        for (String string : list) {
            RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
            color_list.add(get_the_proper_color);
            Drawable drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.color_shape);
            drawable.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(dao.getTagColor(string)), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START);
            lparams.setMargins(i, 0, 0, 0);
            lparams.width = 35;
            lparams.height = 35;
            rl.setLayoutParams(lparams);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                rl.setBackground(drawable);
            } else {
                rl.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
            }

            result.addView(rl);
            i = i + 25;

        }


    return result;
}
```

I also had the same problem in simple custom adapter that it's solved by moving my function place out of

`if (convertView == null) {`

this is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35860515/edit).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per seeing in your code, I found your relative layout must be showing some extra data while scrolling. And  thats because of recycling of views. Here

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) { 
            itemViewHolder.date.setText(items.get(i).getData()); // set the title

            itemViewHolder.relative_layout_tag_place.addView(generateTagImages(items.get(i).getServerId()));  // had to generate a Relativelaout with 
//Problem is here.
```

Suppose you added some child views in above holde.relative_layout , and  this ViewHodler is recyclerd and provided to another item view, It already have all previously added views in it. and you are adding new child view with them. Hope you understand your problem.

Solution: Very easy one. remove all previsousley added view in onBindViewHolder

```
   public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder, int i) { 
            itemViewHolder.date.setText(items.get(i).getData()); // set the title

     itemViewHolder.relative_layout_tag_place.removeAllViews();
   itemViewHolder.relative_layout_tag_place.addView(generateTagImages(items.get(i).getServerId()));  // had to generate a Relativelaout with
```

Answer (score 1):

I was found this solution after 3 day...hope it will work for you.

I had the same problem and the only solution I found for this is:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Your recycler will not recycle anymore so the items will be the same when you scroll, and if you want to delete some item do not use **notifyitemRemoved(position)**, use **notifyDataSetChanged()** instead.

Comment: I think this is not good way, cause we use recycle view exactly to Recycle our Views and better memory management. thanks for answering but check the @Mahendra Answer and I think you had to do like this.

Comment: i had already tried it but not working in my Flow.. so this is worked

Comment: worked for me, but if we have big list then this is not good option for memory management. but after all good answer

Comment: This will make the `RecyclerView` laggy during scroll

Comment: Using this, Its like RecyclerView is committing suicide. If we use `holder.setIsRecyclable(false);` then whats the point of RecyclerView?