# Recycler View showing wrong data when scrolled fast.Have Added Images For The Same

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `RecycleView` where i have three different views for cells. Data is shown perfectly when `RView` is loaded for the first time. As I start to scroll, it changes the view color. Tried different ways but not able to resolve it. 
[original view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luri3.png).
[wrong view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQOJg.png)

```
public class TimelineRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private static final int DATE_LAYOUT = 1;
private static final int EVEN_LAYOUT = 2;
private static final int ODD_LAYOUT = 3;
private List<TimeLineResponseDO.content> contents = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private boolean isVisible = false;
private ConnectionDetector connectionDetector;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private Fragment fragment1;
DateFormat inputFormat;
DateFormat outputFormat;
int counterOnCreate = 0;
int counterOnBind = 0;
public interface OpenSubmissionDetails{
    void openSubmissionDetails(String submissionId);
}
public interface IGetTimeLineData {
    void getTimeLineData(String date);

    void loadSnackBar(String msg);

}
public ProgressDialog getProgressDialog(Context context){
    if (progressDialog == null) {
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.loading_message));
    }
    return progressDialog;
}
IGetTimeLineData getTimeLineData;
public IGetTimeLineData getGetTimeLineData() {
    return getTimeLineData;
}
public void setGetTimeLineData(IGetTimeLineData getTimeLineData) {
    this.getTimeLineData = getTimeLineData;
}
OpenSubmissionDetails openSubmissionDetails;
public OpenSubmissionDetails getOpenSubmissionDetails() {
    return openSubmissionDetails;
}
public void setOpenSubmissionDetails(OpenSubmissionDetails openSubmissionDetails) {
    this.openSubmissionDetails = openSubmissionDetails;
}
public TimelineRecyclerAdapter(List<TimeLineResponseDO.content> contents, Context context, Fragment fragment, IGetTimeLineData iGetTimeLineData) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.context = context;
    this.fragment1 = fragment;
    this.getTimeLineData = iGetTimeLineData;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    connectionDetector = new ConnectionDetector(context);
}

public class TimelineDateHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    Button date;


    public TimelineDateHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);

        date = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
    }

    public void bindViews(TimeLineResponseDO.content response){

            Date date1 = null;

            try {

                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MM-yyyy");

                long dateLong = System.currentTimeMillis();

                String da = simpleDateFormat.format(dateLong);

                Log.e(" Date is :- ", da);

                if (response.getDate().equals(da)){
                    date.setText("Today");
                }
                else {
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getDate()))
                        date.setText(response.getDate());
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getDate()))
                    date.setText(response.getDate());
            }

    }

}

public class TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    RelativeLayout evenContainer;
    TextView subjectTypeEven, timingEven, subjectEven, locationEven, teacherEven, cancelTextEven;
    Button submissionEven, notificationEven ,submissionEvenDetails ;
    ImageView pointerEven, imgCancelBtnEven, imgDelayBtnEven, imgNotificationBtnEven;
    View verticalLine;

    public TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);

        evenContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.evenContainer);
        subjectTypeEven = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subjectTypeEven);
        timingEven = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timingEven);
        subjectEven = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subjectEven);
        locationEven = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.locationEven);
        teacherEven = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teacherEven);
        pointerEven = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circleEven);
        submissionEven = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submissionEven);
        submissionEvenDetails = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submissionEvenDetails);
        imgCancelBtnEven = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtnEven);//#sp 29-09-2016 added
        imgDelayBtnEven = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delayBtnEven);//#sp 30-09-2016 added
        imgNotificationBtnEven = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationBtnEven);//#sp 30-09-2016 added
        notificationEven = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationEven);//#sp 04-10-2016 added
        cancelTextEven = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelTextEven);

        subjectTypeEven.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        timingEven.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        subjectEven.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        locationEven.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        teacherEven.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));

        cancelTextEven.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));



    }

    public void bindViews(TimeLineResponseDO.content response, TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder holder){
            holder.evenContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getSubjectType())) {
                holder.subjectTypeEven.setText(response.getSubjectType());
                Log.d("Ifeven", "" + response.getSubjectType());
            }

            if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals(Enum.LectureSubmission.Submission.toString())) {
                holder.subjectTypeEven.setText(Enum.LectureSubmission.Submission.toString());
                Log.d("ElseIfeven", "" + response.getSubjectType());

            }
            Log.d("LectureSubmEven", "" + response.getLectureSubmission());

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getRoomNo()))
                holder.locationEven.setText(response.getRoomNo());

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getSubject()))
                holder.subjectEven.setText(response.getSubject());

            if (Boolean.valueOf(StorageService.getInstance().getString("IS_STUDENT")))
            {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getTeacherAbbreviation()))
                    holder.teacherEven.setText(response.getTeacherAbbreviation());
            }
            else   if (Boolean.valueOf(StorageService.getInstance().getString("IS_TEACHER")))
            {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getCourse()))
                    holder.teacherEven.setText(response.getCourse());
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getStartTime() + context.getString(R.string.timelineHypen) + response.getEndTime()))
                holder.timingEven.setText(response.getStartTime() + context.getString(R.string.timelineHypen) + response.getEndTime());

            holder.pointerEven.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.timeline_pointer_left);

            holder.timingEven.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.timeline_timing, 0, 0, 0);

            Log.d("resp isSubmission", "" + response.isSubmission());
            if (response.isSubmission()) {
                holder.submissionEven.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.submissionEven.setText(response.getSubmissionCount() + " Submission");

            } else {
                holder.submissionEven.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            Log.d("resp Noti", "" + response.isNotiification());
            if (response.isNotiification()) {
                holder.notificationEven.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.notificationEven.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals("Submission")) {
                holder.submissionEvenDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.submissionEvenDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (response.isCancelled()) {
                ChangeFontColorEven(holder);
            }

            if (response.getSubmissionStatus() != null) {
                if (response.getSubmissionStatus().equals("No")) {
                    ChangeFontColorEven(holder);
                }
            }

        if (response.isEvenLayout()) {
            if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals("Submission")) {
                holder.imgDelayBtnEven.setImageResource(R.drawable.pencil);
            } else {
                holder.imgDelayBtnEven.setImageResource(R.drawable.delay);
            }
        }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getTrnLectureId())) {
            submissionLoadId(response);
        }

        holder.notificationEven.setText(response.getNotificationCount() + " Notifications");

        if (isVisible) {
            if (!response.isDateContainer()) {
                if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals("Submission") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getLectureSubmission())) {
                    if (response.getSubmissionStatus().equals("No")) {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIconsEven(holder, View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIconsEven(holder, View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (response.isCancelled()) {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIconsEven(holder, View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIconsEven(holder, View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

            }
        }else {
            ShowHideEditLectureIconsEven(holder, View.GONE);
        }

    }

}

public class TimelineRecyclerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{


    RelativeLayout oddContainer;
    TextView subjectTypeOdd, timingOdd, subjectOdd, locationOdd, teacherOdd, tvCancelTextOdd;
    Button submissionOdd, notificationOdd , submissionOddDetails;
    ImageView pointerOdd, imgCancelBtnOdd, imgDelayBtnOdd, imgNotificationBtnOdd;
    View verticalLine;

    public TimelineRecyclerHolder(View convertView) {
        super(convertView);

        oddContainer = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.oddContainer);
        subjectTypeOdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subjectTypeOdd);
        timingOdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.timingOdd);
        subjectOdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subjectOdd);
        locationOdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.locationOdd);
        teacherOdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.teacherOdd);
        pointerOdd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.circleOdd);
        submissionOdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submissionOdd);
        submissionOddDetails = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.submissionOddDetails);

        imgCancelBtnOdd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelBtnOdd);
        imgDelayBtnOdd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.delayBtnOdd);  
        imgNotificationBtnOdd = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationBtnOdd);
        notificationOdd = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.notificationOdd);
        tvCancelTextOdd = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cancelTextOdd);

        subjectTypeOdd.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        timingOdd.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        subjectOdd.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        locationOdd.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));
        teacherOdd.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));

        tvCancelTextOdd.setTypeface(NotifyApplication.getExoSemiBold(context));



    }

    public void bindViews(TimeLineResponseDO.content response, TimelineRecyclerHolder holder){
            //holder.verticalLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.oddContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getSubjectType())) {
                holder.subjectTypeOdd.setText(response.getSubjectType());

            }

            if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals(Enum.LectureSubmission.Submission.toString())) {
                holder.subjectTypeOdd.setText(Enum.LectureSubmission.Submission.toString());
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getRoomNo()))
                holder.locationOdd.setText(response.getRoomNo());

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getSubject()))
                holder.subjectOdd.setText(response.getSubject());

            if (Boolean.valueOf(StorageService.getInstance().getString("IS_STUDENT")))
            {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getTeacherAbbreviation()))
                    holder.teacherOdd.setText(response.getTeacherAbbreviation());
            }
            else   if (Boolean.valueOf(StorageService.getInstance().getString("IS_TEACHER")))
            {
                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getCourse()))
                    holder.teacherOdd.setText(response.getCourse());
            }

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getStartTime() + context.getString(R.string.timelineHypen) + response.getEndTime()))
                holder.timingOdd.setText(response.getStartTime() + context.getString(R.string.timelineHypen) + response.getEndTime());


            holder.pointerOdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.timeline_pointer_right);

            holder.timingOdd.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.timeline_timing, 0, 0, 0);

            if (response.isSubmission()) {
                holder.submissionOdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.submissionOdd.setText(response.getSubmissionCount() + " Submission");

            } else {
                holder.submissionOdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            if (response.isNotiification()) {
                holder.notificationOdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.notificationOdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals("Submission")) {
                holder.submissionOddDetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.submissionOddDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            if (response.isCancelled()) {
                ChangeFontColor(holder, Enum.LayoutType.Odd);
            }

            if (response.getSubmissionStatus() != null) {
                if (response.getSubmissionStatus().equals("No")) {
                    ChangeFontColor(holder, Enum.LayoutType.Odd);
                }
            }

            if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals("Submission")) {
                holder.imgDelayBtnOdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.pencil);
            } else {
                holder.imgDelayBtnOdd.setImageResource(R.drawable.delay);
            }

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getTrnLectureId())) {
            submissionLoadId(response);
        }

        holder.notificationOdd.setText(response.getNotificationCount() + " Notifications");

        if (isVisible) {
            if (!response.isDateContainer()) {
                if (response.getLectureSubmission().equals("Submission") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getLectureSubmission())) {
                    if (response.getSubmissionStatus().equals("No")) {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIcons(holder, View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIcons(holder, View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (response.isCancelled()) {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIcons(holder, View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        ShowHideEditLectureIcons(holder, View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }

            }
        }else {
            ShowHideEditLectureIcons(holder, View.GONE);
        }

    }

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    switch (viewType){
        case DATE_LAYOUT:
            View convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.timeline_date_header, parent, false);
            return new TimelineDateHolder(convertView);
        case EVEN_LAYOUT:
            View convertView1 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.timeline_even_layout_child, parent, false);
            return new TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder(convertView1);
        default:
            View convertView2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.timeline_odd_layout_child, parent, false);
            return new TimelineRecyclerHolder(convertView2);
    }

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

    TimeLineResponseDO.content content = contents.get(position);

    switch (itemType){
        case DATE_LAYOUT:
            ((TimelineDateHolder) holder).bindViews(content);
            break;
        case EVEN_LAYOUT:
            ((TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder) holder).bindViews(content, (TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder) holder);
            break;
        default:
            ((TimelineRecyclerHolder) holder).bindViews(content, (TimelineRecyclerHolder) holder);
            break;
    }

    if (position == (contents.size() - 1)) {
        if (connectionDetector.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            getTimeLineData.getTimeLineData(content.getContentDate());
        }
        else {
            getTimeLineData.loadSnackBar(context.getString(R.string.no_internet_connection_schedule));
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contents.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (contents.get(position).isDateContainer()){
        return DATE_LAYOUT;
    }
    else if (contents.get(position).isEvenLayout()){
        return EVEN_LAYOUT;
    }
    else {
        return ODD_LAYOUT;
    }
}

private void ChangeFontColor(TimelineRecyclerHolder holder, Enum.LayoutType layoutType) {
    switch (layoutType){
        case Even:
            break;
        case Odd:
            holder.subjectTypeOdd.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
            holder.timingOdd.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
            holder.pointerOdd.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.timeline_pointer_right_red);
            holder.subjectOdd.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
            holder.locationOdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.teacherOdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.tvCancelTextOdd.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.tvCancelTextOdd.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
            holder.submissionOdd.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.submissionOddDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            break;
    }

}

private void ChangeFontColorEven(TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder holder) {
    holder.subjectTypeEven.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
    holder.timingEven.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
    holder.pointerEven.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.timeline_pointer_left_red);
    holder.subjectEven.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
    holder.locationEven.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.teacherEven.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.cancelTextEven.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.cancelTextEven.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark));
    holder.submissionEven.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    holder.submissionEvenDetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private void ShowHideEditLectureIcons(TimelineRecyclerHolder holder, int visibility) {
    holder.imgCancelBtnOdd.setVisibility(visibility);

    holder.imgDelayBtnOdd.setVisibility(visibility);

    holder.imgNotificationBtnOdd.setVisibility(visibility);
}

private void ShowHideEditLectureIconsEven(TimelineRecyclerEvenHolder holder, int visibility) {
    holder.imgCancelBtnEven.setVisibility(visibility);

    holder.imgDelayBtnEven.setVisibility(visibility);

    holder.imgNotificationBtnEven.setVisibility(visibility);
}

public void editEvent(boolean isVisible) {
    this.isVisible = isVisible;

    Log.d("Is Visible", String.valueOf(isVisible));
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void submission(final TimeLineResponseDO.content timeLineModel) {
    final IGetSubmissionDetails iGetSubmissionDetails = new GetSubmissionDetailsBO();
    iGetSubmissionDetails.getSubmissionByTrn(context, timeLineModel.getTrnLectureId(), new Response<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> callback) throws IOException {
            StorageService.getInstance().putString("SubmissionId", callback.get(0));
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity) context).getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            NoticeBoard noticeBoard = new NoticeBoard();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList("submissionIds", callback);
            bundle.putString("submissionId",callback.get(0));
            bundle.putString("isFrom","submission_view");
            noticeBoard.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, noticeBoard, NoticeBoard.class.getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(NoticeBoard.class.getSimpleName());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e, int i, String msg) {
            Log.d("trnId error",e.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void submissionLoadId(final TimeLineResponseDO.content timeLineModel) {
    final IGetSubmissionDetails iGetSubmissionDetails = new GetSubmissionDetailsBO();
    iGetSubmissionDetails.getSubmissionByTrn(context, timeLineModel.getTrnLectureId(), new ResponseNew<ArrayList<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<String> callback, String id) throws IOException {
            for (int i = 0; i < callback.size(); i++){
                Log.e("trnId error", id + " " + callback.get(i));

                if (AppConstant.initializeDbORReturn(context).isSubmissionIdExists(id, callback.get(i))){
                    Log.e("Already Exists :- ", id + " " + callback.get(i));
                }
                else {
                    AppConstant.initializeDbORReturn(context).insertSubmissionId(id, callback.get(i));
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e, int i, String msg) {

        }
    });

}

private void localTimeLinedb(List<TimeLineResponseDO> callback, Context context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < callback.size(); i++) {
        TimeLineResponseDO timeLineResponseDO = callback.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < timeLineResponseDO.getContentList().size(); j++) {
            TimeLineResponseDO.content content = timeLineResponseDO.getContentList().get(j);
            if (AppConstant.initializeDbORReturn(context).isTimeLineExits(timeLineResponseDO.getDate(),
                    content.getStaticLectureId(), content.getDate(),
                    content.getTrnLectureId(), content.getSlotId(), content.getSubject(),
                    content.getSubmissionId(), content.getLectureSubmission())) {
                AppConstant.initializeDbORReturn(context).updateTimeLine(content, timeLineResponseDO.getDate());
            } else {
                AppConstant.initializeDbORReturn(context).insertIntoTimeLine(content, timeLineResponseDO.getDate());
            }
        }
    }

}

public void getTimeLineData(String date, final Context context, final TimelineRecyclerHolder holder, final Enum.LayoutType even_odd, final Enum.EditLectureType editLectureType) {

    inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
    outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    ITimeLine timeLine = new TimeLineBO();
    TimeLinePostDO timeLinePostDO = new TimeLinePostDO();

    if (date == null) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(StorageService.getInstance().getString("Running_Teacher_Id"))){
            timeLinePostDO.setUserId(StorageService.getInstance().getString("Running_Teacher_Id"));
        }
        else {
            timeLinePostDO.setUserId(StorageService.getInstance().getString("NEWUSER_ID"));
        }
        timeLinePostDO.setUserRoles(StorageService.getInstance().getString("USER_ROLES"));
    } else {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(StorageService.getInstance().getString("Running_Teacher_Id"))){
            timeLinePostDO.setUserId(StorageService.getInstance().getString("Running_Teacher_Id"));
        }
        else {
            timeLinePostDO.setUserId(StorageService.getInstance().getString("NEWUSER_ID"));
        }
        timeLinePostDO.setUserRoles(StorageService.getInstance().getString("USER_ROLES"));
        try {
            timeLinePostDO.setDate(outputFormat.format(inputFormat.parse(date)));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    timeLine.getTimeLineData(context, timeLinePostDO, new Response<List<TimeLineResponseDO>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<TimeLineResponseDO> callback) {

            localTimeLinedb(callback, context);
            getProgressDialog(context).dismiss();

            switch (editLectureType){
                case Cancel:
                    ChangeFontColor(holder, even_odd);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Lecture Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ShowHideEditLectureIcons(holder, View.GONE);
                    break;

                case Delay:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Notification sent for delay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

                case CreateNotification:
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Notification sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }




            if (fragment1 instanceof TimeLineFragment){
                ((TimeLineFragment) fragment1).refreshList();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e, int i, String msg) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: try using holder.setIsRecyclable(false); in onBindViewHolder at the end of the fuction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecycleView adapter data show wrong when scrolling too fast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885021/recycleview-adapter-data-show-wrong-when-scrolling-too-fast)

Comment: Have added images to clear the issue.

Comment: @ZakiPathan i used your solution but it makes recycler view scroll very slow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`RecyclerViewAdapter` recycles its views and thus the behavior is much expected.

When I read your code I saw that you've written `if` statements without `else` like :

```
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getRoomNo()))
            holder.locationEven.setText(response.getRoomNo());

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(response.getSubject()))
            holder.subjectEven.setText(response.getSubject());
```

These will be reused if the view in the position before the newly loaded view doesn't fulfill that `if` statement.

Try adding `else` to your every `if` statement. By adding `else` I mean add something like

```
else {
    holder.locationEven.setText("");
}

// OR

else {
    holder.locationEven.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Ok will try it and reply you.

Comment: Yes it worked. Implement the same way as you suggested and made some changes on my own. Thank you. Saved my day :)

`loadDataOdd(response, holder);


            if (response.isCancelled() || (response.getSubmissionStatus() != null && response.getSubmissionStatus().equals("No"))){
                ChangeFontColor(holder, Enum.LayoutType.Odd);
            }

            else {
                ChangeFontColorBlueOdd(holder, Enum.LayoutType.Odd, response);
            }`

Comment: Yup! I learnt it the hard way lol, glad you got it working fast! :D

Comment: :D bro. Same here :X

Comment: for quick fix, just add `holder.setIsRecyclable(false)` inside `onBindViewHolder`.

Comment: That's not recommended for a `RecyclerView` with many item as they're not getting recycled after setting it to false. It is, however, useful for `RecyclerView` with a small amount of known item (probably 10, I mostly do this for less amount of item like 5 ish), and relatively safe to be coded without if-else